# A reactjs component containing an <img> tag loads a wrong url

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, spring-boot

I'm serving my website from `example.org`, built with reactjs 16.13.1 and typescript.

I have a component that displays an image like this:

`<img alt={""} className={"person-image"} src={person.imageUrl}/>`

The `person` JSON object comes from the backend. ImageUrl is an url that looks like this: `https://example.org/api/data/24361/img.jpg`. The image is served via a Spring Boot controller.

The image fails to load because for some reason it is rewritten to: `https://example.org/example.org/api/data/24361/img.jpg`

Why is `example.org` being repeated?

I inspected the JSON returned from the server and the url is correct: `https://example.org/api/data/24361/img.jpg`

If I copy paste the url on a browser, it loads correctly, so it's not a reverse proxy problem, or it doesn't seem to be.

If I log the url on the console before it's being passed to `<img>`, it is correct.

I have some other images being loaded from external domains and they load without any issue.

Is the `<img>` tag operating some kind of rewriting of the url if the image comes from the same domain and an absolute url is being used? Is there something I'm overseeing?

EDIT: the component code

```
interface PersonProps {
    person: PersonData
    clickable?: boolean
}

export function Person({person}: PersonProps) {
    const actions = [
        new Action(
            <><FullscreenOutlined/> Full</>,
            () => {
                // opens wrong url https://example.org/example.org/api/data/24361/img.jpg
                const win = window.open(person.imageUrl, '_blank'); 
                win?.focus();
            }
        )
    ]

    // prints https://example.org/api/data/24361/img.jpg
    console.log(person.imageUrl)
    return <Wrapper
        actions={actions}>
        {/* loads wrong url https://example.org/example.org/api/data/24361/img.jpg */}
        <img alt={""} className={"person-image"} src={person.imageUrl}/> 
        <div className={"person-body"}>
            {person.name}
        </div>
    </Wrapper>
}
```

Comment: try this once https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader try this once. I think you should edit in for webpack.config.js

Comment: share your react codebase snippet as well, the problem is somewhere there. If you are getting correct data from server.

Comment: @AdeelImran I added the code but I can't spot any mistake. I don't change the url in any way. Maybe in the compilation from ts to js some sugar code is added to automatically pre-pend the domain?